# In highchart, spline misses the continuity for some data

Tags: highcharts

[image]

In the above picture, the spline colour gets hidden(red mark). This occurs only for some data while using filters for date. Could some one give a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your code in jsFiddle?

Comment: Are you sure there's no "white" serie? Are your data sorted?

Comment: It looks like an extra column point which has white color. You can overwrite that by setting index on spline series (index=1). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a6wdguuf/

Comment: Actually, that white space is in the horizontal line, not in the spline. Couldn't find the reason for that.